# How can i determine where php startup failure is occurring in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: php, mongodb, nginx

From cron I see:

```
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/mongo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mongo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

mongo and mcrypt are installed and current.
I also tried:

```
sudo ldconfig -v
```

to no avail.  The directory /usr/lib/php5/20131226/ shows:

```
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  89240 Oct 27 21:40 curl.so
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 114136 Oct 27 21:40 gd.so
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39832 Jan 27  2015 json.so
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  47936 Jan 27  2015 mcrypt.so
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 380400 Jan 27  2015 mongo.so
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 159464 Oct 27 21:40 mysqli.so
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  60504 Oct 27 21:40 mysql.so
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 159896 Oct 27 21:40 opcache.so
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  36168 Oct 27 21:40 pdo_mysql.so
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 118216 Oct 27 21:40 pdo.so
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  31576 Oct 27 21:40 readline.so
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 853376 Jan 27  2015 xdebug.so
```

as I expect.  I am running nginx and not apache, so what gives.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?   I have been looking at this for a few days and am sick of my log files filled with this error.

mongo is compiled into as well.  So where is this comming from?

Thanks!

Comment: The extensions directives in php.ini most likely.  Although, I'm sure there is an issue somewhere, are you sure that listing is from `/usr/lib/php5/20131226`?  If so, then the PHP process must not have access to read that directory since it is saying mongo.so doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes - I will check --- especially saying that mongo.so doesn't exist is VERY strange.  I will query DigitalOcean since they may have done something with permissions for this -- but I don't think so.l

Comment: No help on the DigitalOcean side....